# Change logical sector size to 4k

Tags: linux, partition

Many times asked, but without a conclusive answer: Can you change the logical block size from 512e to 4k (physical block size)?

A solution using `hdparm --set-sector-size 4096` doesn't work under qemu/kvm so i can't really test it, without using a spare device which i don't have.

Can the linux kernel be convinced to switch to 4k sector sizes instead of 512e? Optimally in a way, which can be tested in a VM.

Comment: It is the drive you will have to convince to change sector size. Whether this is possible or not is very much dependent on the drive.

Comment: As soon as I saw the hdparm solution, I was dreading something like that. A quick glance at the kernel source `blk-settings.c` gave me some hope, because the kernel seems to set logical, physical and io_min to a default 512. So if the kernel determines these sizes, i hoped ...

Comment: Could you explain what you intend by doing so?

Comment: Mainly trying to get rid of UEFI/GPT on larger HDDs. But giving an explanation to "WHY" rarely helps with the "HOW". It will most probably escalate into bikeshading and explaining why someone wants to paint his bike red instead of how it's best done. ;-)

Comment: If you don’t need to boot from the drive, and you’re using LVM or Btrfs or ZFS, you can eschew partitions entirely, thus avoiding GPT altogether.

Comment: That's true, but I DO want to boot and I'm not sure if I really want a BTRFS/ZFS only solution. And there are some issues with swap space on BTRFS/ZFS....

Comment: What is that letter `e` after the 512?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the `512e` stands for 512 bytes **e**mulation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format#512_emulation_(512e)

Comment: [**libvirt**](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#hard-drives-floppy-disks-cdroms) let's you set `logical_block_size`, `physical_block_size` and `discard_granularity` for the disks used by the guest.

Answer (score 8):

Changing a HDD to native 4k sectors works at least with WD Red Plus 14 TB drives but **LOSES ALL DATA**. The data is not actually wiped but partition tables and filesystems cannot be found after the change because of their now incorrect LBA locations.

```
hdparm --set-sector-size 4096 --please-destroy-my-drive /dev/sdX
```

This command changes your drive to native 4k sectors. The change persists on drive over reboots but you can revert it by setting 512 at some later time. **REBOOT IMMEDIATELY** after adjusting your disks. Attempt partitioning the drives and adding data only after a reboot (gdisk will then show 4096/4096 sector size).

- The kernel was getting read errors trying to access the drive directly after adjustment. A controller rescan or hotplugging can be used instead, but for most it is easiest to reboot the machine.
- Expect problems if you try to **dd** any disk images created in 512 byte sector size (e.g. .iso files meant for installing distros).
- For NVME SSDs the LBA sector size can be changed with the `nvme` utility (in package `nvme-cli` on Debian based ditros).

Comment: Where is this command? I don't see it in the manual: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hdparm.8.html. Am I doing something silly?

Comment: @GrantCurell look at a newer man page, say one from [Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/man8/hdparm.8.html)

Comment: [**TestDisk**](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) could be used to recover lost partitions.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you change the logical block size from 512e to 4k (physical block size)?

You can ask a drive to change its logical block size. This is what `hdparm --set-sector-size 4096` does.

The fact that this is implemented in the drive has two practical consequences:

- it only works if the drive supports it (as [Johan Myréen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/187960/johan-myr%C3%A9en) [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606072/change-logical-sector-size-to-4k#comment1131325_606072));
- it can only be done by accessing the drive itself, so testing in a VM would only work if the VM is given full access to the target drive.

Comment: I will probably accept your answer, even if i'm unsurprisingly unsatisfied! ;-) Thx for your efforts

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. But you need to modify your system on hard drive level and not on operating system level. The operating system will take care of it.

The next issue you have to keep in mind is that such an operation will break your partition table both MBR and GPT if that drive contains already data.

A simple example to verify what I said is to just duplicate a Samsung S1 Mini drive (1k sectors) to a standard drive (usual 512 byte emulation).

As today's drive mostly run on a 4k native size you will have to patch the firmware (I can't do that) to generate the desired behaviour if your drive's manufacturer doesn't provides you with that option.

When searching for such drives myself I noticed that the manufacturers cash in nice markups for drives that translate physical 4k into logical 4k without "downsizing" to 512. The same applies to the ability to quickly return a read error if a sector read fails (important for RAID arrays). This is just a firmware issue. On typical end user drives the drives read lots of time repeatedly before finally returning an error condition.

Maybe putting in a controller card in between that allows for such a translation could solve the issue - just an idea.

Please let us know how you solved the problem - that is an interesting one!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it appears you want to use msdos style partitions ("to not use UEFI/GPT"), and presumably you want to use 4K sector sizes to allow the maximum partition sizes and disk usage by the msdos partition. One way of doing this in linux is to use the a loopback device to provide a view of the underlying block device that has a different sector size.

```
# truncate -s 20T disk.20T.img
# parted -s disk.20T.img mklabel msdos p mkpart primary 16M 10TB p
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/ubuntu/disk.20T.img: 22.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags

Error: partition length of 19531218944 sectors exceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295
```

Here we can see that creating a 10Tb msdos partition fails on a 20Tb disk with 512 byte sector size. However, when using a loopback device on the disk and setting the sector size to 4K, a 10Tb msdos partition is created and an EXT4 partition can be created using the full partition.

```
# losetup --sector-size 4096 --show -f disk.20T.img
/dev/loop18
# blockdev --getss --getpbsz /dev/loop18
4096
4096
# parted -s /dev/loop18 mklabel msdos mkpart primary 16M 10TB p
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop18: 22.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End      Size     Type     File system  Flags
 1      15.7MB  10000GB  10000GB  primary               lba
# kpartx -av /dev/loop18
add map loop18p1 (253:4): 0 19531218944 linear 7:18 30720
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/loop18p1 
mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 2441402368 4k blocks and 305176576 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 6aa698fa-1cb7-4aa6-9ba6-ebc493d40808
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544, 1934917632

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done       
# mount /dev/mapper/loop18p1 /mnt
# df -h /mnt
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/loop18p1  9.1T   28K  8.6T   1% /mnt
```

If you want to use this in a QEMU virtual machine you can add a disk specifying physical and logical sector sizes of the disk using the properties `physical_block_size=4096` and `logical_block_size=4096`.

For convenience, here's a command I used to test this. You can use any bootable iso you'd like:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -name 'test live cd: bios' -m 2048 -serial stdio -rtc base=localtime \
  -vga std --enable-kvm -cdrom /media/ubuntu/STORAGE/isos/lubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386.iso \
  -boot d -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi1,bus=pci.0 \
  -drive file=/tmp/disk.20T.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk1 \
  -device scsi-hd,bus=scsi1.0,drive=drive-virtio-disk1,id=virtio-scsi-pci1,physical_block_size=4096,logical_block_size=4096
```

Now in the VM you can install do what ever tests you're wanting to do with a 4K drive. Again, if you want to test how an OS handles the live changing of a block device from 512 byte to 4K sector sizes, you're out of luck unless you want to write that emulation into QEMU. Regardless, I think it would be helpful to clarify the question.